# Jquery - find divs with class that contains certain class that has given text value

Tags: jquery

I need some jquery help. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="searchable"><span class="tag">Cool</span><span class="tag">Beautiful</span></div>
<div class="searchable"><span class="tag">Not Cool</span><span class="tag">Tall</span></div>
<div class="searchable"><span class="something">...</span></div>
```

What I need to find are 1) divs with class name "searchable" 2) for these divs, find those that have span elements with class "Tag", because not all searchable divs have tag class 3) find in ANY tags with text value not equal to the world "Cool". So in above example, the second and third divs should be returned. In other words, if any tag has text value Cool, don't return it. And I need to return the "searchable" div, not the span elements.

I've tried this:

```
        $('.searchable .tag:textNotEquals("Cool")').each(function () {
            $(this).closest('.searchable').hide();
        });
```

The textNotEquals are implemented like this:

```
    $.expr[':'].textNotEquals = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
        return function (elem) {
            return !$(elem).text().match("^" + arg + "$");
        };
    });
```

My above code works partially, only the first match is returned. If I have multiple div matches, it doesn't work. Also, I was hoping there is an easy way to do this. My code seems too complex. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain this can't be done with selectors alone. You'll have to concoct something.

For example:

```
$('.searchable').filter((idx, el) => $(el).find('span.tag').map((idx, el) => $(el).text()).get().indexOf('Cool') === -1);
```

In English, find all `class="searchable"` elements in which there are no `<span`class="tag">` elements containing the single word 'Cool'.

Alternatively, invert the logic and use `.not`:

```
$('.searchable').not($('span.tag').filter((idx, el) => $(el).text() === 'Cool').closest('.searchable'));
```

In English, find all `class="searchable"` elements but exclude those in which there is at least one `<span`class="tag">` element containing the single word 'Cool'.

*Both approaches may simplify with further effort*

Comment: Thanks for the code! The first one seems to be working for me. However, I am not able to pass a variable to it. The word 'Cool' is a variable but when I change it to the actual variable, it doesn't work.         
        $('.searchable').filter((idx, el) => $(el).find('span.tag').map((idx, el) => $(el).text()).get().indexOf("' + tag + '") === -1).hide();

Comment: I've got it -- $('.searchable').filter((idx, el) => $(el).find('span.tag').map((idx, el) => $(el).text()).get().indexOf(tag) === -1).hide();

Comment: That should do it.